# UIImagePickerController iOS8 issue

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

The problem is with iPhone6 (iOS 8.1 and iOS 8.1.1) and UIImagePickerController

I use code:

```
self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [self.imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    self.imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
    self.imagePickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;

self.imagePickerController.view.layer.borderWidth = 2;
        self.imagePickerController.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

[self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But after that on **iPhone6** I see the camera view without bottom part (everything is OK on iPhone4s iOS 8.1):

[image]

Comment: this is the same issue with iphone5 and 6 plus. I guess its because of the longer screen size.

Comment: Do you use native screen resolution for big screens?

Comment: @bpolat, how can I check (buy in my Storyboard I have autolayout and size classes enabled, so I think I have native resolution)

Answer (score 0):

The top part of the image has a ratio of 4:3, to make the camera feed to full screen, you can do the following.

```
CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
// set the aspect ratio of the camera
float heightRatio = 4.0f / 3.0f;
// calculate the height of the camera based on the screen width
float cameraHeight = screenSize.width * heightRatio;
// calculate the ratio that the camera height needs to be scaled by
float scale = screenSize.height / cameraHeight;

// move the controller to the center of the screen
self.imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, (screenSize.height - cameraHeight) / 2.0);
// concatenate the scale transform
self.imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform, scale, scale);
```